# Replace only capturing group - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to replace `strong` tag with `b` tag. To do this I have created a regex `/<\s*\/?\s*(strong)\s*>/gi`. I only want to replace capturing group `(strong)` only. But it replaces whole tag with be.
Example:

```
"My name is <strong>Tariq</strong>".replace(/<\s*\/?\s*(strong)\s*>/gi,'b');
```

but its results in
`My name is bTariqb.`

What is wrong here...?

Comment: Can't you just make your replacement `<b>`, and capture the `/` (if present) to add that in (`<$1b>`)?

Comment: If you're just replacing one tag, why not just `.replace('<strong>', '<b>').replace('</strong>', '</b>')`?

Comment: @BenFortune This is only sample. My original HTML will contain more than one tag.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Here is an issue that my HTML may contain more than one strong tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:*
Final addition: while the expressions below will work in most cases, they can't cope with markup like this:

```
var example = "I want to <strong>replace</strong> all strong tags with the <i class='strong-text stronger'>better</i> b tag";
```

The tags will be replaced just fine, but note the class attribute: `strong-text stronger` will be replaced with *"b-text ber"*. As far as `stronger` is concerned: adding word-boundaries will fix that issue, but `strong-text` will still cause problems.
We have to make sure that the matched substring *"strong"* is not an attribute of any kind. Thankfully, this is an easy fix: attribute values are preceded by an equal sign, and 99% of the time, single or double quotes. Using the following pattern, then, prevents us replacing attribute values:

```
example.replace(/(<[^>="']*?)\bstrong\b([^>]*>)/gi, "$1b$2");
//result:
//"I want to <b>replace</b> all strong tags with the <i class='strong-text stronger'>better</i> b tag"
```

*Pattern explanation:*
- `(<[^>="']*?)` same as below, but we've excluded `=`, `'` and `"` from being the match, meaning `<p class="strong">` won't match, as there is a `=` char between the opening `<` and `strong`.
- `\bstrong\b`: added word-boundaries (see below)
- The rest of the pattern remains unchanged.

Anyway, that's probably as close as you're going to get to a reliable pattern. Still: look into using an XML parser if you're planning on consuming a lot of markup, because RegExp is *not* the best tool for the job

---

***Initial answer***

You want to replace *"strong"* with *"b"*, and leave everything else as-is, right? Well in that case, you should group everything *except* that which you are trying to replace, and use back-references to the groups in your replacement string:

```
"My name is <strong>Tariq</strong>".replace(/(<\s*\/?\s*)strong(\s*>)/gi,'$1b$2');
```

As ever: RegEx is not the best tool for consuming markup languages, and your pattern is not perfect: it can't handle tags with attributes, for example. Change the pattern to matching in a *"everything-except"* way, rather then *"match this or that"*:

```
/(<[^>]*?)strong([^>]*>)/gi
```

How it works:

- `(<[^>]*?)`: Match and capture `<` followed by *any* char (0 or more) that is not `>`. Non greedy, match will end as soon as the rest of the pattern is found
- `strong`: literal match for string
- `([^>]*>)`: Match zero or more non `>` chars, and a closing `>`. This match is also captured
- Replace entire match with `$1b$2` or `<group1>b<group2>` this preserves any attributes and/or spaces the markup contained.

As a result, markup like this is processed correctly:

```
"My name is <strong id='someId'>Tariq</strong>".replace(/(<[^>]*?)strong([^>]*>)/gi,'$1b$2');
//output:
//My name is <b id='someId'>Tariq</b>
```

Inspired by Harpeet's (somewhat flawed) regex, you could also opt to use this pattern:

```
str.replace(/\bstrong\b(?=[^<>]*>)/gi, 'b')
```

If nothing else, it is a more elegant looking pattern.

Explained:

- `\bstrong\b`: matches string literal, if it is not part of a word (`\b` are word boundaries)
- `(?=[^<>]*>)`: only if it is followed by 0 or more chars that aren't `<` or `>`, and a closing `>`. If we omit the `<` from the exclusion group, you risk replacing the word `strong` when it's not part of a string: `'a strong sense<br>'.replace(/strong(?=[^>]*>)/gi,  'b');` results in *"a b sense"*.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh: I'd like to +1 you, too, because your initial answer gave me the idea to suggest `/\bstrong\b(?=[^<>]*>)/gi`. Though not entirely reliable, it's an elegant approach. Your current answer is worng, so I can't +1 that. Please roll back the changes, and maybe change your pattern with what I made of it, or, if you want: the most accurate version I could come up with, with your pattern as a starting point: `str.replace(/(<[^>'"=\/]*\/?)[^>='"]*?\bstrong\b(?=[^<>]*>)/gi, "$1b")`, but that's not as elegant anymore :-S

Comment: [details + example](http://regex101.com/r/kK3eP7) - Sorry, I like regex, I played around with this pattern a bit

Comment: I have rollbacked my answer but I am not adding your regex as my answer. +1 is not a need. Stack is for learning and helping. I have many answers with 0 votes but still I love to answer/help. It makes me to learn more. I will play around with your solution and if I am able to crack alternative for lookbehind concept from your answer, then it will be a +Millions_Of_K's for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a short way would be this

```
"My name is <strong>Tariq</strong>.'.replace(/(<\/?)strong(?=[^>]*>)/gi,'$1b');
```

here's also a short explanation:

```
(<\/?)strong(?=[^>]*>)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PHNgGSRH-Ux2_jMf)

Comment: Your replacement string doesn't work: JS back-references are `$<digit>`. Your pattern also doesn't deal with unexpected white-spaces, or tag-attributes

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem ... mhh... I'll try to figure out your annotations, thx

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: well you were correct, there was an issue... the replacement should be `$1b` instead of formerly `b\1`.
The rest is and was absolutely correct (tested, now ^^)

Comment: `'foo < strong class="bar">Bold</ strong>'.replace(/(<\/?)strong(?=[^>]*>)/gi, '$1b')` => if a tag contains a space somewhere, your pattern still fails, though

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: `< strong>` is incorrect syntax. IMHO this regex should not be responsible for fixing the input code. you would need to sanitize that in the first place.

Comment: @aeno: Agreed: it's bad style, but the OP's pattern suggests malformed tags _can_ occur. To fix that, he really ought to use a parser, which makes this whole regex business rather pointless (as I stated in my answer anyway), which is exactly why regex + markup = bad idea

Answer (score 1):

RegEx you need is

```
/strong(?=>)/g

"My name is <strong>Tariq</strong>".replace(/strong(?=>)/g, "b")
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hL5vE0)

Comment: There's a problem here: tags like `<strong class='box-view'>` are not processed, and adding `?=[^>]>` to the look-ahead isn't quite sufficient (`<i> a few strong men</i>` => `<i> a few b men</i>`). I have taken your idea and came up with a usable alternative, though

Comment: No problem: your initial pattern was better, and easier to fix though, as I explain in my answer: `/strong(?=[^<>]*>)/g` is enough. And it looks elegant, still.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem is mine still flawed? If no then please remove (somewhat flawed) from your answer.

Comment: It's a minor issue, but `"<strong>I</strong> am getting rid of all the strong tags".replace(/strong(?=>)|((?:=<)?strong)/g, "b")` replaces the last _"strong"_, which is not a tag, too: _"<b>I</b> am getting rid of all the b tags"_. It also replaces _"strongest"_ with _"best"_. The latter is a simple matter of adding word boundaries: `\bstrong\b`, though

Comment: The main reason why your updated pattern works, is because you made the non-capturing group optional (JS regex's don't support look-behinds!): `(?:=<)?strong` matches an optional string literal `=<`, and a non-optional `strong`. That means that _all_ occurrences of _"strong"_ are being matched

Comment: +1 for a very elegant starting point. Though not a must, I hate to see people who take time to work on their answers go unrewarded for their efforts.